# google appengine --log_level not showing print statements

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, pycharm

I run my web app using the following command

`dev_appserver.py app.yaml`

I am trying to debug my application and have tried to put print statements in the code. print("Hello") but do not end up seeing it in the terminal or the console.

Then i tried using "logging."

```
import logging

logging.info("hello")
logging.debug("hi")
```

I rerun the webapp using the following command

`dev_appserver.py app.yaml --dev_appserver_log_level=debug`

Using this, i get alot of noise and still the logging statements don't show.

How can i just show my own print statements? Is there a better method to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The description for `--dev_appserver_log_level` says

> the log level below which logging messages generated by the development server will not be displayed on the console (this flag is more useful for diagnosing problems in dev_appserver.py rather than in application code)

so i think it just sets the log level of `dev_appserver.py`'s logger.

But there's `--log_level` too which says

> the log level below which logging messages generated by application code will not be displayed on the console (default: info)

so maybe try setting that to `debug` too since it defaults at `info`

Also have you just tried doing this:

```
logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
```

Comment: i am still confused about where does that `logging.get...` statement go.

Comment: You can organize your log statements into different loggers. This `tcp_logger = logging.getLogger('tcpserver')` will init a logger named `tcpserver`, after which you can do `tcp_logger.info('my log')`. If you dont want to do that, you can just do `logging.info("hello")` to use the root logger. `logging.getLogger()` just grabs the root logger and `.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)` sets the min level of logs you want to see from that logger.

Comment: "i am still confused about how to print statements to the console" confused meaning that you are unable to do it? or meaning you dont know how it works?